# DRF : AttributeError: 'BlogSerializers' object has no attribute 'get_uri'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Can anyone explain about the problem.

mobel.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_api_url(self):
        return api_reverse("post-rud", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

and my serializer file is serializer.py

```
class BlogSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    uri = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = [
            'uri',
            'pk',
            'user',
            'title',
            'content',
            'timestamp',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['pk', 'user']

        def get_uri(self, obj):
            return obj.get_api_url()
```

error showing

> AttributeError at /api/blog/post/list/ 'BlogSerializers' object has no
>   attribute 'get_uri'

if i use under this line than problem is solved. But i wanna understand about this error.

```
class BlogSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # uri = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='get_api_url')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the `get_uri` method to the meta Class, instead of your serializer class.
Just remove one indentation level and you are good to go.